# What method of joining entities is faster?

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, jpa, jpql

Here are two queries retrieving equivalent data:

```
SELECT DISTINCT packStatus
  FROM PackStatus packStatus JOIN FETCH packStatus.vars, ProcessEntity requestingProcess
    WHERE
      packStatus.status.code='OGVrquestExec'
      AND packStatus.procId=requestingProcess.activityRequestersProcessId
      AND requestingProcess.id='1000323733_GU_OGVProc'

SELECT DISTINCT packStatus
  FROM PackStatus packStatus JOIN FETCH packStatus.vars
    WHERE
      packStatus.status.code='OGVrquestExec'
      AND packStatus.procId=(SELECT requestingProcess.activityRequestersProcessId FROM ProcessEntity requestingProcess WHERE requestingProcess.id='1000323733_GU_OGVProc')
```

These queries differ in the method how `requstingProcess` is joined with `packStatus`. In general, which of these two methods is more preferable in terms of performance? I'm using JPA 1.2 provided by Hibernate 3.3 on Postgres 8.4.

UPD: I've replaced fake queries with real queries from my app. Here is SQL generated by Hibernate for [first](http://paste.org.ru/?v770v7) and [second](http://paste.org.ru/?6usbpf) query. Links to query plans: [first](http://explain.depesz.com/s/a2O), [second](http://explain.depesz.com/s/QNf). Query plans look pretty the same. The only difference is what moment data from bpms_process table is aggregated to query result at. But I don't know is it right to generalize these results? Would query plans be almost the same for queries differing only in joining method? Is it possible to get a big difference in query cost by changing joining method?

Comment: You may want to take a look at [Explain](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/sql-explain.html) to be able to test the two queries yourself. But generally the one with the sub-query is going to be slower.

Comment: @jschoen Frequently they're transformed into the same query plan anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Use `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` and see.

I won't be surprised if they get turned into the same query plan.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info